# Java Regex return contiguous words and numbers into arraylist

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a Java RegEx routine that will return an arraylist with the following requirements"

1. Remove special characters
2. Add a String to the arraylist of contiguous alpha characters and contiguous numeric characters.
3. A space or series of spaces is the delimiter.

Here is the input:

```
Az ma9n,  66  a pk0 lan, a c55an*()al: Pan3afffma
```

Here is the expected output of what should be in the ArrayList:

```
Az, ma, 9, n, 66, a, pk, 0, lan, a, c, 55, an, al, Pan, 3, afffma
```

Here is what I have but it's not even close:

```
String test = "Az ma9n,  66  a pk0 lan, a c55an*()al: Pan3afffma";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
test = test.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9|\\s]", "");
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-z+A-Z+0-9+]").matcher(test);

while(m.find()) {
    list.add(m.group());
}

System.out.println(list.toString());
```

Comment: Use `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\p{Digit}+|\\p{Alpha}+").matcher(test);` or if you need to support Unicode, `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\p{N}+|\\p{L}+").matcher(test);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "Az ma9n,  66  a pk0 lan, a c55an*()al: Pan3afffma";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Pattern to match either sequence of digits or that of letters
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+|[A-Za-z]+");

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            list.add(matcher.group());
        }

        // Display list
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Az, ma, 9, n, 66, a, pk, 0, lan, a, c, 55, an, al, Pan, 3, afffma]
```

Comment: Sweet!  I guess the brackets separate the groups?

Comment: You are most welcome. Square brackets are used to group characters or range(s) of characters from which any one has to be matched. I strongly recommend you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Java 9 or above, you could write it in a compact way using  `Matcher#results()` :

```
String test = "Az ma9n,  66  a pk0 lan, a c55an*()al: Pan3afffma";
List<String> list= Pattern.compile("\\p{Digit}+|\\p{Alpha}+")
                          .matcher(test)
                          .results()
                          .map(MatchResult::group)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```